# How to avoid re-created threads when using multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading

My main purpose is: Every 10 minutes, the app syncs the time on server. Then, the clock will start from the time get from server while the countdown clock will show the remaining time till the next sync.

My code is below. It seems the thread is re-created every 10 minutes, so the clock display wrong. But, I don't know how to fix it. Please help me. Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private AnalogClockView analogClockView;
    private FrameLayout analogLayout;
    private long now;
    private ClockAsyncTask mClockAsyncTask;

    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10*60*1000, 1000) {
        @Override 
        public void onFinish() {
            mClockAsyncTask = (ClockAsyncTask) new ClockAsyncTask();
            mClockAsyncTask.execute();                  
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            analogClockView.updateTime();
            analogClockView.postInvalidate();
        }
      };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        analogLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.analogLayout); 
        mCountDownTimer.start();        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class ClockAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {            
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            getNTPTime();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            analogClockView = new AnalogClockView(MainActivity.this, now, analogLayout.getWidth()/2, analogLayout.getHeight()/2);
            analogLayout.removeAllViews();
            analogLayout.addView(analogClockView);
        }
    }

     public void getNTPTime(){
        SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
        if (client.requestTime("0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org", 1000)) {
            now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                    - client.getNtpTimeReference();
            Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
            current.setTimeInMillis(now);               
        }
     }   
}
```

Comment: Why threads with an AsyncTask? Also, why not a Timer/CountDownTimer?

Comment: @user2864740: When I use SntpClient to get time from server, it causes exception when I don't put it in AsyncTask. In addition, this post said that Timer isn't good http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the code feeds the *same* Runnable used for the thread *back* into postDelayed without end. The threads *only run for a very brief moment of time*, but the the code keeps posting messages (and each message posts another (and each message posts ..)).

One solution would then be to use a variable to decide when to *not* post another event.

```
// Not really a "Thread"
public class CountdownRunner implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        if (countdownRunning) {
            MainActivity.this.updateHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            // STOP calling when then the countdown is over
            // The fundamental problem is this series of delayed postbacks
            // is never sopped in the original code.
            updateHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    } 
    public void cancel() {
       // ..
    }
}
```

Also, *ditch* creating new threads because explicit threads serve no purpose here: the run method for the Runnable provided is only invoked *once* on the thread, and then the thread dies. (The subsequent invocations of the run method are on the UI thread in response to the postDelayed callbacks.)

```
private CountdownRunner countdown;

protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    // Start the countdown with the time from the server,
    // cancelling the previous countdown as required.
    if (countdown != null) {
        countdown.cancel();
    }
    // No "new Thread"! this is running on the UI thread and all
    // subsequent executions of run for this instance will also be
    // on the UI thread in the postDelayed postback.
    countdown = new CountdownRunner();
    countdown.run();
}
```

---

While the above *explains* the problem, I would suggest simply using a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) as it nicely encapsulates the logic:

> [A CountDownTimer schedules] a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals along the way.

Then the flow trivially goes like this:

- Create a CountDownTimer and update the UI with the time remaining each `onTick`. When the countdown is over and `onFinish` event fires, create a new AsyncTask.
- Have the AsyncTask (i.e. ClockAsyncTask) download the time in the `doInBackground` method. In the `onPostExecute` method, create a new CountDownTimer.
- Repeat this cycle indefinitely; make sure to cancel any CountDownTimers as appropriate.

Comment: So, I have to change Thread to CountDownTimer in my code? After get time from server, the clock still runs by itself, and we don't use Thread?

Comment: The explicit threads in your code are *useless*. It is confusing that the Runnable is used for the Thread *and* the delayed postback because it's only in a new thread the *first* time the `run` method is called on the instance. I recommend using a CountDownTimer because it nicely encapsulates the logic: "Do this every so often"

Comment: What's about the clock? Every 10 minutes, mClockAsyncTask = (ClockAsyncTask) new ClockAsyncTask(); Is it ok? In addition, when I want to stop the countdown timer to sync time manually, how can I do that?

Comment: See `if (countdownRunning) {` (however that expression is controlled is on you, I recommend add a "stop" or "cancel" method with a flag); but if you *used* a CountDownTimer, then you could `cancel` it..

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying with CountDownTimer now. But when I update the GUI for the clock, I still use Thread?

Comment: Update the UI in the `onTick` event of CountDownTimer. **Do not** use `new Thread` in this code, as it is not needed. (You will also want to use delta time math in the code; simply incrementing a counter will lead to drift.)

Comment: What's about AsyncTask? Can I keep it?

Comment: Yes, keep the AsyncTask. As you found/pointed out, the network UI has to be done in "doInBackground" which is *not* run on the UI thread.

Comment: Please check my new code, it get NullPointerException

Comment: @lolyoshi NullPointerExceptions are something that developers should be able to resolve. Find out *where* the exception is occur and then reason *why* it is occurring (the ultimate issue is trying to invoke a member upon `null`). Attach a debugger if needed.

Comment: I know it's caused by the AsyncTask. I should create AsyncTask before I start the countdowntimer. However, I want AsyncTask running again every 10 mins. Are there any solutions or I have to re-create a new AsyncTask?

Comment: Yep, it works now but I noticed that the GUI didn't update when the timer finishes. Thus, it seems missed 1 sec every 10 mins

Comment: @lolyoshi I've added a short set of rules for how to simplify the code with a CountDownTimer. In any case that "not updating when the timer finishes" is because the  `MainActivity.this.updateHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);` isn't called in that case - so call it as appropriate. However, no time is "lost" because of the *independent* 10 minute timer. I recommend unifying both timers with a single CountDownTimer.

Comment: I see, but when I display it in the screen, the time of last tick is 10.01 and it doesn't update to 10.02 but it start with the new clock at 10.03.